# javascript click function using jquery...strange behavior

Tags: jquery, function, click

I'm new at javascript and jquery and have used this site (and others) to try and figure out why the click function in the fiddle below does not properly work.

When you run the code, you'll see a checkbox and textarea, even when the checkbox is not selected. The correct behavior should be; only show the textarea when the checkbox is selected. I'm sure i'm missing something simple here.

Any help is much appreciated.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdugge/sfrwnems/)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="OtherAdv" name="OtherAdv" value="1" data-mini="true" /><label for = "OtherAdv">Other?</label>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="formfont_small" id="OtherAdvDiag" name="OtherAdvDiag" data-mini="" placeholder="Please list others"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#OtherAdv').click(function () {
         var $foo = $(this);
         if ($foo.is(':checked')) {
             $('#OtherAdvDiag').show();
         } else {
             $('#OtherAdvDiag').hide();
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: You're not hiding anything initially, and it seems to work if you check, then uncheck the checkbox. A `$('#OtherAdvDiag').hide();` before your click function would seem to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not accounting for the starting state of the checkbox - you're acting only on future state changes.

This can be remedied in several ways. If you know the checkbox will always begin unchecked, you could simply hide the textarea in your CSS. Or, for more dynamism, you can use `trigger()` to fire the event on load, in which case your existing callback will take care of the problem, just as if someone had actually toggled the checkbox.

Updated code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#OtherAdv').on('change', function () {
        $('#OtherAdvDiag')[$(this).is(':checked') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

I also cleaned up and optimised your code a little, in several areas. In particular, use change, not click, events with checkboxes, as the former takes into account toggles done via non-mouse means also, e.g. keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine, the `textarea` just isn't hidden by default.  You can hide it with CSS, for example:

```
#OtherAdvDiag {
    display: none;
}
```

Or if you want to keep the functionality with the JavaScript, just hide it once when the page loads:

```
$('#OtherAdvDiag').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfrwnems/1/) you go

You need to hide the textarea when the page loads by including

```
style="display:none"
```

Comment: Why not use the handy input box for CSS instead of an inline style in the markup?